# Custom query_var causes displaying posts archive on front page

Tags: query, frontpage, query-variable

I'm having an issue which is caused by custom query var named `date` I've added using `query_vars` hook. When `date` parameter is present in the front page URL (https://example.com/?date=23.08.2016), WordPress is loading posts archive instead of just front page. When other random params are added to the link (https://example.com/?foo=bar) or no params are present, front page is loaded correctly the static page I defined.

Posts page in the backend is different than front page.

I added custom query var using following code:

```
my_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'date';
    return $vars;
}

add_filter( "query_vars", "my_query_vars" );
```

Any idea why such a thing happens?

Comment: It's a known bug: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25143

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After detailed debugging of `WP::parse_request()` and `WP_Query::parse_query()` I found out that `unset( $query_vars['date'] );` in `'request'` filter helps.

It basically unsets date query var before `WP_Query::parse_query()` is invoked so `is_home()` returns false.

```
add_filter( 'request', function( $query_vars ) {
        global $wp_query, $wp;

        if ( ! $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
            return $query_vars;
        }

        $qv_keys = array_keys( $wp->query_vars );

        if ( ! ( in_array( 'product_cat', $qv_keys, true )
           || in_array( 'product_tag', $qv_keys, true )
           || in_array( 'post_type', $qv_keys, true ) && 'product' === $wp->query_vars['post_type']
           || in_array( 's', $qv_keys, true )
        ) ) {
            unset( $query_vars['date'] );
        }

        return $query_vars;
} );
```

**Explanation:**

Posts archive loads when `WP_Query::$is_home = true` so I traced back places where this value is set and in brief I think it's like this:

1. `$this->query_vars['post_type']` and `$this->query_vars['name']` are not set [in this condition](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L323) as date query var is not assigned with any post type.
2. In result after many operations `WP_Query::$is_singular` is set to false [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1779)
3. And it leads to `WP_Query::$is_home = true`.

Comment: Your solution strips the query var you're creating and makes it unavailable to methods such as `get_query_var`